# Calling service method from another service class

Tags: java

I have two service classes. WarehouseManagementService provides methods to administrate warehouses and stocks. SalesManagementService provides methods to manage customers and their orders.

To create an order, it is necessary to check, if the order item quantity is sufficient. For this I would use the method availableStock(Product p) in the WarehouseManagementService. But I do not know, how to call this method properly.

Do I have to create an instance of WarehouseManagementService in SalesManagementService? Or should I add the WarehouseManagementServiceInterface to the SalesManagementService constructor (dependency injection)?

What could a good architecture look like, to achieve a loose coupling of these two classes?

Thanks in advance.

```java
public class WarehouseManagementService implements WarehouseManagementServiceInterface {

    private DatabaseReadWarehouseInterface dbRead;
    private DatabaseWriteWarehouseInterface dbWrite;

    public int availableStock(Product p) {
    // returns available quantity of product
    }

}
```

```java
public class SalesManagementService implements SalesManagementServiceInterface {

    private DatabaseReadSalesInterface dbRead;
    private DatabaseWriteSalesInterface dbWrite;

    public void addOrder(Order o) {
    // creates order, if product quantity is sufficient
    }

}
```

Comment: are you using spring framework?

Comment: No, I am not using spring framework. Since it is a small study project, it is not intended to be used

Comment: alright then you need to create objects of services in each other

Comment: @Mustahsan: I disagree. Also without using Spring, you should de-couple dependencies.

Comment: Constructor dependency is the best option instead of creating an object of a class.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have the right feeling: The dependency should be injected. Just remember the [Single Responsibility Principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle): "A class should have only one reason to change".

By constructing `WarehouseManagementService` in `SalesManagementService`, you would add a second reason for `SalesManagementService` to change: When the way of constructing your `WarehouseManagementService` changes.

To solve it, you could either use a full-blown Dependency Injection framework, or simply start by adding a constructor parameter to `SalesManagementService`:

```
public class SalesManagementService implements SalesManagementServiceInterface {

    private DatabaseReadSalesInterface dbRead;
    private DatabaseWriteSalesInterface dbWrite;
    private WarehouseManagementServiceInterface warehouseManagementService;

    constructor(DatabaseReadSalesInterface dbRead,
                DatabaseWriteSalesInterface dbWrite,
                WarehouseManagementServiceInterface warehouseManagementService) {
        this.dbRead = dbRead;
        this.dbWrite = dbWrite;
        this.warehouseManagementService = warehouseManagementService;
    }

    public void addOrder(Order o) {
    // creates order, if product quantity is sufficient
    }

}
```

Then in your `main` method, take care of instantiating `WarehouseManagementService` and pass it to `SalesManagementService`.

As a sidenote, you might want to move the construction of `SalesManagementService` and `WarehouseManagementService` into factories which give you a `SalesManagementServiceInterface` and a `WarehouseManagementServiceInterface` rather than the concrete classes ("program to interface, not implementation").